# Testing a model with a one-to-one relationship

Tags: django, selenium, django-forms

Im testing my app and am really stuck on how to test my personalInformation form which has a one-to-one relationship with my user. I have tried a lot of things but here is the testing code boiled down to the stuff im pretty sure is correct and a few related classes.

models.py

```
class PersonalInformation(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    GENDERS = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
    )

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDERS)
    dob = models.DateTimeField('Date of birth (mm/dd/yyyy)', null=True, default=now)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username}'
```

forms.py

```
class PersonalInformationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PersonalInformationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit'))

    class Meta:
        model = PersonalInformation

        fields = ['first_name', 'surname', 'gender', 'dob']

        widgets = {
            'dob': DatePickerInput(
                options={
                    "format": "MM/DD/YYYY",
                    "showClose": False,
                    "showClear": False,
                    "showTodayButton": False,
                }
            ),
        }
```

unit test

```
def test_user_information_updated_on_success(self):
        user = User.objects.create_superuser('username')
        self.client.force_login(user)
        form = PersonalInformationForm(data={
            'first_name': 'testuser',
            'surname': 'testsurname',
            'gender': 'M',
            'dob': '1984-09-17 00:00:00'})
        form.save() # form.save throws error
```

error msg

```
1048, "Column 'user_id' cannot be null"
```

This isnt correct as 'first_name' is an attribute of personalInformation, which has a one-to-one relationship with the user

```
self.assertEqual(user.first_name, 'testuser')
```

-- EDIT --

Following Arakkal Abu's advice I now get

```
Duplicate entry '12' for key 'user_id'
```

I think maybe I should be testing this by calling

```
self.client.post(
    '/enrolment/personal_information/', data={
    'first_name': 'testuser',
    'surname': 'testsurname',
    'gender': 'M',
    'dob': '1984-09-17 00:00:00'}
)
```

so im calling the POST method on the page im testing, but it doesnt update the attributes as when i call

```
assertEqual(user.personalinformation.first_name, 'testuser')
```

it is blank.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Use **`commit=False`**

```
def test_user_information_updated_on_success(self):
    user = User.objects.create_superuser('username')
    self.client.force_login(user)
    form = PersonalInformationForm(data={
        'first_name': 'testuser',
        'surname': 'testsurname',
        'gender': 'M',
        'dob': '1984-09-17 00:00:00'})


    instance = form.save(commit=False)
    instance.user = user
    instance.save()
```

**Ref:** [Django Model form `save()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method)

Comment: Thank you very much. However I am now getting (Duplicate entry '1' for key 'user_id'') which confuses me as there is no other users in the db (being a unit test I cant see how this error would occur). Thank you

Comment: There is another instance of `PersonalInformation` in your ***test database***. That's why the error.

Comment: In order to not create another instance of PersonalInformation I am guessing I should call 'self.client.post' with the personalinformation data passed into it. However it doesnt save this to my user model (AssertionError: '' != 'testuser') (my personalInformation POST view should save the posted data to the user - it does when im not testing)